# Eclipse Workspace build while saving JSPs and XML files

Tags: eclipse, jsp, build, workspace

Whenever I am trying to save any JSP or XML file..Eclipse is trying to compile all the files in the workspace, also copying all the .svn files to the classes directory, causing the build to be very slow. Is there any flag in eclipse to avoid this problem?

Thanking you in Advance.
Abdul Rab Khan

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off automatic builds at all, but I'm not aware of optnion about turning it off only for JSPs.

As for .svn - install subclipse - it should manage things like ignoring svn files.
You can also use `filtered resources` in `preferences > java > compiler > building > output folder`.